# Which software allows Miracast over infrastructure (MS-MICE) "Wireless display" sink on the RPi other than lazycast?

Tags: ethernet, display, wireless

Note at present time, MiracleCast does not support MS-MICE therefore the RPi cannot serve as a ethernet wired display for a windows computer.

Comment: You are asking for a software which doesn't have a certain "minor issue" that you didn't describe?

Comment: Ok deleted reference to minor issue